# Simple query using jquery/javascript from a onchange selected value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

In this example the alert(selectedString) retrieves the dropdown selection value so I know this part works.  I would like to take that value and use it to query a table with mysqli and PHP. How can we query a database table using the selected string?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var select = document.getElementById("test");

select.onchange = function(){
var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;


alert(selectedString);

}

</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX to call a php script and pass the selected string as your data parameter.  You can then echo the results array of the query and then update your Dom with the results on the success callback

Answer (score 0):

use jQuerys [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). to make a asynchronous call to your server while the user is on the website. in the `data` property pass the selectedString and read it in your php script with `$_GET['selectedString']`. on the client side you might like do something with the returned data from the php request in the `done` block.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourServerScript.php",
  data: { selectedString: selectedString },
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( html );
  });
```